# Oracle Apex position of link column in interactive report

Tags: oracle-apex

I created a default page using latest version of Oracle Apex with interactive report and linked report page for editing and creation of new items.  By default my link button is showing in a first column. I need to show that link as an item in a very last column instead. Can't find any settings in the designer that would allow me to re-configure that. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not currently a design time option for this, nor a runtime one if you're using the 'Link Column' definition in the IR Attributes.

I would recommend defining your own column, and set the attributes as desired, if you want it to look like a button etc. That way, you can use the Actions menu at runtime to define exact placement.

[image]

More info on styling your links, and other things (in context of classic report)

http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html